# Not Found: /style.css/ , django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to create my own website on Django, but some problems stop me and I can't solve them myself.
I want to create a sidebar. I found a website with css and HTML code for it.

style.css:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600|Open+Sans:600&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  left: -240px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.sidebar header{
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar a{
  display: block;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 65px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
a.active,a:hover{
  border-left: 5px solid #b93632;
  color: #b93632;
}
.sidebar a i{
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.sidebar a span{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}
label #btn,label #cancel{
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #262626;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 29px;
  background: #262626;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
label #cancel{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
  left: 0;
}
#check:checked ~ label #btn{
  margin-left: 245px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#check:checked ~ label #cancel{
  margin-left: 245px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
@media(max-width : 860px){
  .sidebar{
    height: auto;
    width: 70px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 100px 0;
  }
  header,#btn,#cancel{
    display: none;
  }
  span{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 23px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .sidebar a{
    height: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar a i{
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  a:hover {
    width: 200px;
    background: inherit;
  }
  .sidebar a:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

sidebar.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Sidebar Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <header>My Menu</header>
      <a href="#" class="active">
        <i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
        <span>Shortcuts</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-stream"></i>
        <span>Overview</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
         <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
        <span>Events</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
        <span>About</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i>
        <span>Services</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <span>Contact</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All of these works if I start it in any snippet, or if I just run sidebar.html from pycharm in google, but when I start my site it doesn't work and gives an error: Not Found: /style.css/
Both files are on the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix, but you will need to dig into Django a bit more.

First, this tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href=style.css/>` will never work. The tag is written wrong on a few levels. The big problem is that the location is relative, the use of `style.css` is assumed to be on the same directory level as what ever page/script/etc is being called.  The problem is that wsgi.py or similar file is actually the "root" that is "running" the site and has no idea where "style.css" exists and also deos not care.

Styles, image, js, etc are all stored as static assets in Django.  This folder is "served" using a `static` tag that will transform to the correct path per your configuration for local dev and production. Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

I will not explain all the nuance, the Django site does a better job.  Instead I will point out how Django is different from static sites or something like PHP.  Django is an application running in the CGI (WSGI), there is only one "route" on the server so to speak, all data is served from this one file. PHP can and typically does serve data in a file+directory manner. In PHP/static scenario the location of files is stable compared to Django. In Django the page, url, and the way data is served all come from one point. That means the relationship to static files will be different and not something you can or should control.

Django does not want you to ever serve static files through the CGI (WSGI), that is a waste of CPU and resources and is slow for static. So they have a static system. When running locally with the configuration set up correctly and `DEBUG=True` then the `static` keyword will transform to the necessary local path in conjunction with your configuration.

When in production it is assumed that a CDN is used, in that case the `static` keyword is replaced with the path (URL) to the CDN static files.

The approach Django uses is much more mature than say, Wordpress where use of a CDN can be tricky (I have written custom CDNs for WP many times, not fun).

Walk through the link above, set up your configuration correctly and follow the rules. Django is very interested in your following of the rules, Deviation will only cause pain. I have been primarily a Django dev for almost 10 years now. The problem you ran into got me real good in the beginning, but now CDN and static file management is second nature and definitely more productive than other less mature systems.

Comment: I can't rep your answer up, so I will say thank you here! It helped! Thanks!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Set static root on your 'settings.py'.

Comment: I added in my settings.py
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
 
then I tried to create static/css/style.css
I changed in sidebar.html to href="{% static css/style.css %}" but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to change `<link rel="stylesheet" href=style.css/>` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`. Also, the path it is trying to find your `style.css` file in is like this: `(whatever path to your sidebar.html)/sidebar.html/style.css`. I doubt that it is located there. If it is located in the same directory as your `sidebar.html` file, try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>`

Comment: Ye, I tried to do it with "" and '', it doesn't work..

Comment: Then your path isn't correct in relation to your ```sidebar.html``` file.

Comment: Templates (.html files) are rendered via the application and you MUST USE the static keyword in templates (or do something not good to work around not using the system in place).  There is no path or "relative" path in the templates as you know it in Django.  HTML template files are hydrated, part of the hydration is substitution of key words with correct logic.  Because of this you use the static handlers.